# Improve Eigen performance - best practices

Tags: c++, performance, eigen

I have the following code that uses `Eigen` matrices:

```
template<class T>
T lfactorial(T x)
{
    return static_cast<T>(std::lgamma(x + 1));
};

void eigen1(const MatrixXd& m, const MatrixXd& a)
{
    MatrixXd W = a.unaryExpr(ptr_fun(lfactorial<double>));
    const auto sum = m.unaryExpr(ptr_fun(lfactorial<double>)).sum();
}
```

Is there a faster way to compute the matrix `W` as well as the `sum`?

In my program I have to compute a lot of matrices by applying unary expressions to the same input matrix. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Even if there is more to calculate than the factorial -- don't use the Gamma function. It's by far more complex as compared to the usual `n * (n-1) * ... * 1`.

Comment: @davidhigh it should be the log of the factorial of x, for some reasons if I don't use the lgamma function I get nan values.

Comment: The log-factorial of n is simply `log(n) + log(n-1) + ... + log(2)`. I would calculate that recursively and use memoization. If that is what you asked for I can formulate an answer. With respect to the `unaryExpr( ... )`, I guess there is not much you can do to speed it up -- Eigen just applies the functions, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lgamma function has been [added to the Eigen API](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/pull-requests/148/add-special-functions-to-eigen-lgamma-erf/diff) recently, and will therefore be supported natively in the next version of Eigen.

The next version will be released soon, in the meantime you can download the beta version at http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.3-beta1.tar.bz2